# What does it mean by 'out of the air'?

Tags: meaning

> A low rumbling sound had broken the silence around them. It grew steadily louder as they looked up and down the street for some sign of a headlight; it swelled to a roar as they both looked up at the sky - and a huge motorcycle fell **out of the air** and landed on the road in front of them. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Dictionaries have ‘out of thin air,’ but not ‘out of the air.’ Then do I have to read the phrase literally?

Comment: yep, this one's literal.

Comment: There is a similar phrase "out of the blue". Though this also has a general meaning of something coming out of nowhere, or something that is unexpected.

Comment: In English, there are a few "out of" phrases that mean something is surprising, like "out of left field," or "out of nowhere." These phrases all mean that something arrived unexpectedly. A phrase like "That car just came out of nowhere" would mean that the car's arrival was a complete surprise. In the Harry Potter book, this phrase is kind of a joke, because in this case the motorcycle actually fell from the sky, which is not where we expect to see motorcycles coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is meant literally, because the motorcycle DID fall from the sky. But more often, "out of the air" is meant figuratively, in the sense of "from a random place."

Answer (score 2):

It means "*out of the sky*" as in the huge motorcycle was flying in the sky [in the air above him].